# Nested SingleChildScrollView

Tags: scroll, flutter

I have a widget with nested SingleChildScrollView in SingleChildScrollView. It is possible to scroll down outer scroller when inner scroller reaches bottom and scroll up when inner one reaches top.

Answer (score 3):

**SingleChildScrollView** has a property called `physics`. Set `physics` to `SingleChildScrollView()` as shown below:

```dart
    SingleChildScrollView(
        physics:NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    )
```

Comment: I didn't find this physics class

Comment: its a property inside SingleChildScrollView

Comment: The argument type 'SingleChildScrollView' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ScrollPhysics'.

Comment: @mirkancal that was my mistake

Comment: its NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()